# Django filter by ForeignKey-attribute as User

Tags: python, django, database, filter, foreign-keys

I'm using a Django framework to make a database-application. I have a my database structure as classes. A "Horse"-class that have a ForeignKey relationship with a "Rider"'-class, which in turn have a ForeignKey relationship with the User.

It's all working, but I want to filter the horses so only the horses that are connected to the current User will show.

```
file: models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Horse(models.Model):
    name = ...
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Rider')

class Rider(models.Model):
    name = ...
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

So when I render my html-page, I want to filter the horses accordingly:

```
file: views.py

from .models import Horse

def Horses(request):
    horses = {
        'horses': Horse.objects.filter( ??????? )
    }
    return render(request, 'stable/horses.html', horses)
```

So if I'm logged in as "Admin", how do I pass this into the filter, so all horses that have a relationship with a rider that have a relationship with this user will show?

Seems to be something different when referring to a ForeignKey-object instead of just an attribute that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You can look "through" relations with two consecutive underscores, so you can filter `Horse` objects such that its `owner` has as `user` the authenticated user with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def horses(request):
    horses = {
        'horses': Horse.objects.filter(owner__user=request.user)
    }
    return render(request, 'stable/horses.html', horses)
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, therefore it is
>   advisable to rename your function to `horses`, not <s>`Horses`</s>.

Comment: Oh wow! Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much sir! Great notes also!